# Search by main color (hex code) and get all color related to that hex?

Tags: php, colors, hex

Supposing that I have 1000 color hex codes in my database. 
**Data Stored in database is hex code e.g. ffffff,000000,etc.**

I'd like to let the user search by main colors such as blue, red, green, orange, black, white, etc.

For example, if the user search by blue, I'd like to show all blue-related colors e.g. dark blue, light blue, very light blue, etc.

Is this possible and how to implement this on PHP?

Comment: Which database do you use? And already tried something?

Comment: It is possible. Yeah.

Comment: use the mysql `like` statement to find entries in your database that have partial string matches

Comment: It seems that I made everyone misunderstanding my question.

Data Stored in database is hex code e.g. ffffff,000000,etc.

Comment: Well, if the user choose 'white', mean that they choose 'ffffff'. So, how to display white-related colors e.g. light grey?

Comment: oke can you tell us the names in the table? that you use? not the names of the values but of the columns

Comment: ok guys, you don't have to create any sql query for me.
What I want is to sort hex code like this picture.
http://www.photopattern.com/075dmcolors.jpg

Comment: If you do not restrict the terms/words a user can search for then this is a natural language processing problem with arbitrary complexity.